# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/(k(k+1)(k+1)!)=3-e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

This is my attempt. I start with calling the sequence $x_n$:

$$x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} = \frac{A}{k} + \frac{B}{k+1} + \frac{C}{(k+1)!}$$

Multiply both sides by $$(k(k+1)(k+1)!$$

$$1 = A(k+1)(k+1)! + B(k)(k+1)! + C(k)(k+1)$$

Using $$k=0 \rightarrow A=1$$, $$k=-1 \rightarrow B=-1$$, and $$k=1 \rightarrow C=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Rewrite the sequence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)!}\right]$$

The first two terms form a telescoping series:

$$1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \ldots + \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

For the last term in the sequence, we can add and subtract $$\left(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!}\right)$$.

Now, the last step is to sum the two results:

$$1 - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=-1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!}\right)$$

Taking the limit as (n) approaches infinity, we get:

$$1 - 0 - \frac{e}{2} + 1 = 2 - \frac{e}{2}$$

"The right answer is $3-e$."

Where is the mistake and I tried so much to use partial fraction decomposition method but it didn't work

Last thing I will drag the book's solution for this question:
[image]

I want someone to help me know how did the author evaluate the right-hand side equation??

Comment: It's $\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)!}$, not $\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Hint: write $\frac1k=\int_0^1x^{k-1}dx,\,\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_0^1y^kdy$, susbtitute $z=xy$, then change the order of integration to rewrite the sum as$$\int_0^1\frac{(1-z)(e^z-1-z)}{z^2}dz=\left[z+\frac{1-e^z}{z}\right]_0^1.$$

Comment: I tried my best to fix some mistakes guys can you give a look to my attempt?

Comment: PFD is not applicable, because of the factorial.

Comment: Oh i see...but how did the author solve it what did he do to get the right-hand side equation?

Comment: I don't see how to derive that expression on the right, but we can verify it by induction.

Comment: Hmm maybe...I thought about changing variable in the summation like considering (k+1)=m and try to manipulate to get to the equation of RHS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use partial fractions just for the first two factors:
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$$
Now here's a straightforward derivation of the book's solution:
\begin{align}
x_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)!} - \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k\cdot k!} \\
&= \frac{1}{1(1+1)!} + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)!} - \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\cdot k!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{(k+1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}\right) - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{(k+1)!}-\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}\right) - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&= 3 - \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Great solution!!